# Clean up package manager cache on nixos with full root partition

Tags: nixos

On Ubuntu when the root partition gets full you can always run `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean` to free up some space for the package manager to continue working. But the equivalent command on nixos seems to have some issues running on a full root partition:

```
$ nix-collect-garbage
...
error: committing transaction: database or disk is full
```

Quite the pickle to be in when the reason you're running `nix-collect-garbage` to begin with is to clean up the full disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you'll have stuff stored in `/tmp` you can remove to free up the space needed for `nix-collect-garbage` to complete.

```
$ rm -r /tmp/*
```

Comment: Do you intend to remove the /tmp directory itself? Otherwise, I'd suggest something like `rm -r /tmp/*`.

Comment: Usually, `/tmp` is mounted into RAM so it won't help in those cases